# URL transliteration in Views rewrite?

Tags: views, transliteration

I have a [View](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) of taxonomy terms and for some reason I need to overwrite the terms' fields and link them "manually", using "Output this field as link". How can I process the '[name]' token through [transliteration](https://www.drupal.org/project/transliteration) process before outputting it on the screen?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a workaround that worked for me.

Prerequisites: Pathauto and Transliteration modules.

1. Add a new text field to your taxonomy called "cleaned_name", or whatever you like. In a later step we will populate this field at view execution with the term name after passing it through pathauto_cleanstring.
2. Add the "Taxonomy term: Name", and "Taxonomy term: cleaned_name" to your view. The "cleaned_name" field must be below the "Name" field.
3. In the view settings for the "Name" field, mark the "exclude from display" checkbox.
4. In the view settings for the "cleaned_name" field, click on "Rewrite results" to open the rewrite settings, then mark the "Rewrite the output of this field" checkbox.
5. This will cause a textbox to appear, where you can build your link html. For example:

   ```
   <a href='PUT-YOUR-PATH-HERE/[field_cleaned_name]'>[name]</a>
   ```
6. Next implement hook_views_pre_render. The idea is to take the the name, run it through pathauto_cleanstring, and store it in the cleaned_name field.  I used the following code:

   ```
   function YOUR_MODULE_NAME_views_pre_render(&$view) {
       if ($view->name == "MACHINE_NAME_OF_YOUR_VIEW") {
          //dpm($view->result); INSTALL DEVEL MODULE AND UNCOMMENT THIS IF YOU NEED TO SEE WHAT FIELD NAMES TO USE
      module_load_include('inc','pathauto');
      foreach($view->result as $key => &$result) {
         $cleaned_name = pathauto_cleanstring($result->taxonomy_term_data_name);
     $result->field_field_cleaned_name[0]['rendered']['#markup'] =  $cleaned_name;
      } // End of FOREACH statement
      unset($result); 
        }
   }
   ```

Adding a field to your taxonomy just to have a place to return a transliterated version of your field is a little ugly. Another alternative I tried was to add the name field to the view twice, with the idea of running only one of them through pathauto_cleanstring, and thus having both a clean and uncleaned version available as tokens to build the link. This did not work however, because although you can add the term name field twice to a view, and views will create two tokens ([name], [name_1]), in the backend both tokens point to the same field. If we modify this field, both tokens will output the modified value.

Another alternative I tried was to build the link html inside the hook_views_pre_render function, and use that to overwrite the value in $result->taxonomy_term_data_name. That avoids the need to add a field to the taxonomy. However, the problem here is that views will escape the html when it displays it. I wasn't able to find a way around this.